# Use Android classes in custom annotation processor

Tags: java, android, annotations

Some context on what I need custom annotations for, in case my approach is the wrong one for this case.

I have several classes (Missions) that are stored in a local SQLiteDB / built from said DB. The logic for saving each mission is to use a ContentValues and add each field to said ContentValues (and the opposite logic to reconstruct them from the DB).

This poses a problem, because any time I need to add/remove a new field to the super Mission class, I have to do the following, **for each sub mission**, to include the new field:

- Change the table declaration.
- Change the `saveToDB()` method.
- Change the `getFromDB()` method.

This may not seem like much but my model is actually getting pretty big, with several SubMissions, which leads to a huge time waste whenever I need to slightly change something.

So what I thought was I could create a custom Annotation and processor to generate the table declarations as well as the saveToDB/getFromDB methods.

The problem with that approach is that, as mentioned above, I save the objects in a ContentValues, which is an Android object. And, since the custom processor (as per [this link](https://engineering.wework.com/custom-annotations-in-android-af43514f2f1b)) is created as a Java Library, I can't access the ContentValues.

How could I solve this?

(by the way, I also considered using Reflection to create generic `addMissionToDB()`, `getMissionFromDB()` and `createMissionTable()`. I don't really want to do it this way because of performance reasons unless it's unequivocally the best way to do it though)